# Need help using Python to find and count different reoccurring elements in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am relatively new to Python and I was wondering if it were possible to use python to count specific reoccurring elements in something like a text file. For example, if the file had:

```
ID1002
ID1002
ID1001
ID1003
ID1003
ID1003
```

Would it be possible to count how many times each id appears and store that information somewhere? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Of course it is, but this is not a code-writing service.  Go investigate `collections.counter`.

Comment: Will investigate right now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You could use the `readlines()` function to get a list of all the IDs and use the `.count()` function.**

```
f = open("yourfile.txt")
counts = {}

for i in f.readlines():
    counts[i] = f.readlines().count(i)
    
print(counts)
```

This code goes through the list containing all the IDs and saves the ID and the number of times the ID occurs in the file to a dictionary.